# hide div if submit is clicked and div with class "row" is present

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would you mind telling me if this is the most efficient way to write this script? It works when i add it to jsfiddle but having trouble with it on my site. I want to hide the div with class "nores" if the div with class "row" is present when submit is clicked.

```js
$('h2').append('<br /><div class="nores">no results found</div>');
$('#submit').on('click', function(nor){
    if ($('.row').length > 0) {
  $('.nores').hide();
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" type="submit">
<h2>
search results
</h2>

<div class="row">
some text
</div>
```

Comment: What problems exactly are you having when you implement it in your site?

Comment: Is the JavaScript running after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: Use your debug tools in your browser (like chrome dev tools) and look for javascript errors in the console.  If it's working in jsFiddle, but not on your site, most likely you have a JS error or conflict that's causing this to fail.  Also what, Spencer May said.. if this script is trying to run before the objects are in the DOM, it will fail. Set your script up to run after the page is loaded.

Comment: I tried setting a timeout and no errors are being pulled

Comment: If it works on the fiddle, but not your site, then you have things interfering with one another on your site, but without seeing the rest of the relevant code, we can't really help you with that, because what you showed here is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a bit unclear, but I think the solution is in there:

- Encapsulate your code in `$(document).ready(function () {});` or `$(function () {});` to be sure that it will be executed when the DOM is ready.
- Use event delegation to take advantage of bubbling. This is a good practice to avoid unexpected problems with your listeners. You can read the following article if you need inspiration: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
- Organize your JavaScript code using modules. Otherwise, you will most likely have conflicts because of the mess in the global scope... If you do not want to bother with AMD or CommonJS, you can simply refactor your code like this:

  ```
  var module = {
    init: function () {
      module.listeners();
    },
    listeners: function () {
      $('#submit').on('click', module.submit);
    },
    submit: function () {
      if ($('.row').length > 0) {
        $('.nores').hide();
      }
    }
  };

  $(document).ready(module.init);
  ```